# How to fix the Auto Layout issue on the official iOS app development tutorial?

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

At end of [Implement Edit and Delete Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) section of the official iOS app development tutorial, it is mentioned that the layout has errors and fixing these errors using stack views is left as an exercise for the reader.
To fix them, I have followed the following steps:

1. Add a horizontal stack view, which will contain the UIImageView and a vertical stack view.
2. Constrain the edges of the horizontal stack view to the edges of the superview.
3. Add the label and Rating Control to the vertical stack view.
4. Set Content Mode to Aspect Fit in UIImageView.
5. Set CHCR properties of UIImageView to all 1000.

[image: Your Meals Scene]

However, the layout is still not to my liking. For example, I have started the app in iPhone 5 simulator and this is the situation:

[image: Your Meals Scene on iPhone 5]

The image views do not extend to cell top and bottom (with keeping the aspect ratio). Furthermore, when I tap "Edit", the image views shrink instead of the Rating Control and Label:

[image]

Similarly, when we slide a row left, instead of the label and Rating Control being shrank, the image view is slided out of the view:

[image]

I would like the image view stay there completely and Rating Control and Label to shrank as necessary.

I have also tried replacing the Rating Control with a plain Horizontal Stack View, which contains 5 plain buttons. This is the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This time, the UIImageView covers the whole cell. I have expected:

1. The UIImageView's height equal to the height of the cell.
2. The UIImageView's width is proportional to its height (because I have set the Content Mode of UIImageView to Aspect Fit in the Interface Builder).
3. The remaining space to be covered by the label and the new Rating Control. They should take up the *remaining space*, because I have set the CHCR of the UIImageView to all 1000.

## Update:

Here's the view after adding an Aspect Ratio constraint to the Image View:

[image]

[image]

It is nearly done, except the fact that the image view does not start at the left edge. To fix this, I have tried setting image view's leading edge position to the superview's leading edge position but this did not help.

How can I achieve the desired layout?

Answer (score 0):

The swipe to delete part is working exactly as it should. The whole cell is sliding to the left not shrinking to the left (take a look at Mail.app and you will see it behaves the same way).

As to the other issue you are having with the image view being the only part that shrinks when the table is in edit mode…

1. Turn down the compression resistance of the rating view and label.
2. Add an aspect ratio constraint to the image view.
3. Select the image view and content view (easiest to select with the
   command key in the outline view you took screenshots of) and set
   them to have equal heights.
   This should keep the image view from shrinking while in edit mode. If not experiment with the various mode for the horizontal stack view at the top level of the cell.

Comment: Adding the Aspect Ratio constraint fixed the problem of image view shrinking (see edit). However, the problem of image view not attached to the left edge of the cell still persists.

Comment: See the first sentence in my answer, the image view isn't supposed to be visible when the user swipes the cell to the left. The idea is that the _entire_ cell is moving over to reveal the delete button under it. There is no way that you can use the swipe to delete functionality and still see the entire cell. The left edge will _always_ be hidden from view. If you want the image to always be visible even during a swipe you will have to swap it to the right hand side of the cell.

Comment: I am not talking about the swipe to delete. I am talking about how the table appears on app load. Please see the first image of my latest edit.

Comment: The aspect ratio of the images versus the ratio of the image view is getting you. If you look in the original version the image touches the left edge of the screen and it is right up against the rating view and label. In the new images there is space on both sides of the image. The image looks to be really close to square but the image view is likely a bit wider than the height (look at the aspect ration to confirm). Try removing the ratio, setting the image view to the same dimensions as the images themselves, then add the ratio back.